# What is the overhead when keeping AD refrences?

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

Is there any overhead of keeping a reference to a `GroupPrincipal` ? I am performing regular `Add` and `Remove`s to a target group and i do not know what are best practices when working with `System.DirectoryServices`

I am regulary performing:

```
GroupPrincipal grp=..... ;
grp.Members.Add();
grp.Members.Remove();
```

Is it more cost effective to just spawn new objects everytime i perform an operation or keep a refrence directly to the group i am working with .

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with keeping a reference to it. You will have better performance that way, since every time you create a new `GroupPrincipal` it will go out to AD to find the group.